Do I have to show a notification when my web page is in the foreground and has focus?
I have a web Javascript application that would like to make use of the Push API to send data-only messages to browser clients without any kind of "visual" notification-associated data in the payload.
I am unclear about whether the Push API allows browser clients to receive a Push API message without demanding the client to call showNotification().
A few questions have been raised in the past regarding this "silent push" feature, such as
Push API without Notification API
However, the following page section "the exception to the rule" suggests that it is possible to programmatically determine if the current browser window has the focus and is in the foreground
https://web.dev/articles/push-notifications-common-notification-patterns#the_exception_to_the_rule
and, based on the result (i.e. in focus, or not in focus), display or not a notification.
Isn't it possible/allowed to send data-only messages to browser clients silently, as long as the web page is in the foreground and has focus?

A notification is not linked to a any particular browser tab / window, they can even be no tabs / windows open for it to work.   So it doesn't seem to make sense what your trying to do.  If your not going to show a notification, why not just fire an update event when the browser window next gets focused.. ?
